# String replacement using modulo in Python for raw_input?

Tags: python

Is it possible to produce the following somehow?

```
name = raw_input("Enter name: ")
age = raw_input("Hello %s, please enter your age") %name
```

I know I can substitute a + to concatenate the strings, but I was curious if this would work somehow.

Comment: when if ask you for input  -- then just enter `%s`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put the variable inside parentheses

```
age = raw_input("Hello %s, please enter your age" % name)
```

Answer (score 3):

You should do it using the newer python string formatting:

```
age = raw_input("Hello {0}, please enter your age".format(name))
```

It gives you [many more formatting options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/python-string-formatting-vs-format). Do read.

Comment: @user3556942, Nope. Python2 as well. And __really__ useful in some cases. Your choice :)